# Help For A Simple Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to extract 34 from this string. How Can i done that ? (i will use javascript)

```
#project_maincategory=3&project_subcategory=34&project_tags[]=70&project_tags[]=71&created_in=30
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to parse the parameters, or to recognize "34" specifically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var src   = "#project_maincategory=3&project_subcategory=34&project_tags[]=70&project_tags[]=71&created_in=30",
    match = /project_subcategory=(\d+)/g.exec(src);

    alert(match[1]);
```

Anyways, it looks like a query string so there should be a better way to parse/read that string. See http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/AdamAnderson/07-12-17/Parse_a_Query_String_in_JavaScript.aspx

Comment: @mTuran: whoops, my bad. fixed!

Answer (score 0):

`.*project_subcategory=(\d*).*`

Comment: The `.*` at the start and the end aren't needed.